# How can i report to the user when counting files in real time the counting?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In a backgroundworker dowork event i'm calling this method:

```
public List<string> FindLines(string DirName, string TextToSearch)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        List<string> findLines = new List<string>();
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(DirName);
        List<FileInfo> l = new List<FileInfo>();
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, "Counting Files");
        CountFiles(di, l);
    }
```

And the method CountFiles:

```
private void CountFiles(DirectoryInfo di, List<FileInfo> l)
        {
            try
            {
                l.AddRange(di.EnumerateFiles());
            }
            catch
            {

            }

            try
            {
                IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> subDirs = di.EnumerateDirectories();
                if (subDirs.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in subDirs)
                        CountFiles(dir, l);
                }
            }
            catch 
            {
                string err = "";
            }
        }
```

This is the progresschanged evet:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.UserState.ToString() == "Counting Files")
                label2.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
        }
```

It's taking 2-4 seconds more or less to count the files. In this time i'm showing the user a message that it's counting files now but if i want also to show on label3 the real time counting of the files how can i do it ? I think i need to reportprogress somehow from inside the CountFiles method ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the first CountFiles call to this:

```
 CountFiles(di, l, count=> {
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(count, "Files Found...");
            });
```

Change CountFiles method to this:

```
 private void CountFiles(DirectoryInfo di, List<FileInfo> l, Action<int> CurrentCount) {
           ...
            foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in subDirs)
                CountFiles(dir, l, currentCount=> {
                    CurrentCount(l.Count);

                });
        }
```

Comment: john I tried. Since subDirs not exist I changed it in my code to di. But now i'm getting error on the foreach: Error 3 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo' because 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: Start over, your code makes no sense. It seems Directory.GetFiles would serve you better. You could have it fetch the files of the directory only (not recurse over children). Then do the recursion yourself and raise your event after each call to GetFiles.